# OllyDbg, don't get the option to copy to executable file

Tags: ollydbg

Whenever I'm in OllyDbg and successfully finish editing the ASM code to my liking, I try to highlight all the modifications I've made and when I right click....I don't get the option to "Copy to Executable?" - Yet a lot of the tutorials I follow have this option, and they do it in the videos.

Details:

OllyDbg2
Windows 7 x86
Running OllyDbg as an administrator
No plugins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of two things happened if you cannot right click -> edit-> copy to excutable.

1. You edited within the data section of the executable which it has nothing to copy then.
2. You made your edits outside of the main module. If you edited any of the dll's then you cannot copy it to executable also.